# Trying to extract value via xpath of variable, not getting correct result

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am trying to get this value via xpath.

[image]

```
<td width="50%" class="col">
<table class="item" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
  <th>Area (m²)</th>
  <td class="value">
    <strong>165</strong>
  </td>
</tr>
```

i am trying to grab the actual integer value (165)

this is the xpath I am getting via debug tools

```
/html/body/div[4]/section/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/strong
```

I am trying to gather information on this property listing and i am trying to capture the area of an apartment.  I have played around with the xpath that i get from the debugger but i always get either an empty string or an error that says u cant turn a xpath selector into a string.  Not sure where to go with this to get the 165 value.

Please, any input u can provide, i have looked at this for several days.

```
area = response.xpath('/html/body/div[4]/section/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/strong')
print(area)
```

via this xpath i am expecting the 165, but i get nothing.  i just get this `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use relative XPath instead of absolute:

```
area = response.xpath('//td[@class="value"]/strong')
print(area)
```

or

```
area = response.xpath('//th[.="Area (m²)"]/following-sibling::td/strong')
print(area)
```

Comment: that worked thanks.  but now i get a list that has this kind of input . [u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t105\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'] . How do i get the value out of that? The lists on each apartment are diff lengths ie. i cant just do area[0] or area[1].

Comment: @joe , try `for value in area: print(value.strip())`

Comment: this goes through the whole list.  i want to only extract the value.  
area:
area:
area:
area:
area:
area:
area:
area:
area:
area:
area:
area:
area:
area:
area:234
area:
area:
area:
area:   i want to extract the 234

Comment: i tried checking if value:, but they are not empty strings

Comment: @joe try to check `if value.strip()` to ignore values that are just a set of spaces/new-line characters

Comment: Thanks,  i am trying to get another variable that is very similar to the one above.  This is the xpath i get :                                                                                               "//*[@id="offerdescription"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/strong/a" . how would u do the relatvie path of this?  bc it seems like it would conflict with the relative path i used before.

Comment: @joe , I need to see HTML for the same. Do you mean you want to select values from both cases when text in `strong` and text in `strong/a`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186353/discussion-between-joe-and-andersson).

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
xpath = '//table.item/tr[contains(., "Area")]/td//text()'
```

`//` relative path selection

`table.item` select table with `item` class

`tr[contains(., "Area")]` Checks for all trs having text 'Area'

`td//text()` for the `tr` having text 'Area' select `td` of that `tr` and 
`//text()` extracts every text. which is probably 165.